# How to use tensoflow make such a Calculation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

two tensor 
x = [a,b,c]
y = [d,e,f]
both float32 numbers
I want to get a tensor like this z = [ad,ae,af,bd,be,bf,cd,ce,cf]
this is jsut a simple example
the real tensor may be huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could reshape x to be of shape (3, 1) and y to be of shape (1, 3).  Then when you multiply them they will broadcast and give you a (3, 3) array which can be flattened.  Here is an example with numpy.  Tensorflow behaves in the exact same way and has equivalent functions (except use `tf.reshape(z, [-1])` to do the flatten since there is no flatten in tensorflow.)

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([4, 5, 6])
z = np.expand_dims(x, 1) * np.expand_dims(y, 0)
z = z.flatten()
```

This gives me `array([ 4,  5,  6,  8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18])` as the output.